# Dell ePort Plus II (K09A002) not recognized under linux

Tags: linux, drivers, dock

The Dell ePort Plus II docking station is not recognized under linux (both Fedora 22 kernel-4.0.6-300.fc22.x86_64 #1 SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux and Ubuntu 14.04).

The bug is similar to the one reported and WONTFIXed in [this kernel bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51351) (acpidump is same with or without dock) so the problem is on Dell side it seems.

How can I investigate and where can I report ? [I tried the [dell forum](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19640506) without success]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, my issue is linked to using a underpowered adaptor (130W instead of 210W?). Windows with dell drivers does warn about it, Linux doesn't.